# Generate random json for given json-schema in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

For testing our project, I want to generate random json objects respect to a given json-schema, how can I do this work?
The given json-schemas won't be really complex.

Comment: haven't done this before, but you could try to use a combination of http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and http://code.google.com/p/jeneratedata/

Comment: Tnx, i will try to code it by myself.

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40035338/4989929,If it helps.